# Customise file_view to view pdfs in the browser

Tags: plone

I am still running Plone 3.0.6 for our Intranet.  I have tried to upgrade to current version, but always come up against a road block.  I'll have another go at that later when I have more time.

For now, I just need to customise /portal_skins/plone_content/file_view to make it open pdf attachments in the browser instead of downloading them.  We are installing a new kiosk system that will display PDFs in the browser but can't browse and view files in the filesystem.

I've done a lot of searching and found others who have done this, but not for the version I'm running.  I'm not a developer of any sort, so I can't figure out how to do what they have done on my system.

Here is the current code for file_view.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"
      xmlns:tal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/tal"
      xmlns:metal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/metal"
      xmlns:i18n="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/i18n"
      lang="en"
      metal:use-macro="here/main_template/macros/master"
      i18n:domain="plone">

<body>

<div metal:fill-slot="main">
    <tal:main-macro metal:define-macro="main" 
           tal:define="size python:here.getObjSize(here);
                       content_type here/get_content_type|here/Format;
                       kssClassesView context/@@kss_field_decorator_view; 
                       getKssClasses nocall:kssClassesView/getKssClassesInlineEditable">

        <div tal:replace="structure provider:plone.abovecontenttitle" />

        <h1 class="documentFirstHeading"> 
            <metal:field use-macro="python:here.widget('title', mode='view')">
            Title
            </metal:field>
        </h1>

        <div tal:replace="structure provider:plone.belowcontenttitle" />

        <p class="documentDescription">
            <metal:field use-macro="python:here.widget('description', mode='view')">
            Description
            </metal:field>
        </p>

        <div tal:replace="structure provider:plone.abovecontentbody" />


        <p>
            <metal:field use-macro="python:here.widget('file', mode='view')">
            File
            </metal:field>
        </p>

        <div tal:condition="python: content_type.startswith('text')">
            <h2 i18n:translate="heading_file_contents">File contents</h2>
            <pre tal:content="here/get_data|here/data|nothing">
            </pre>
        </div>

        <div metal:use-macro="here/document_relateditems/macros/relatedItems">
            show related items if they exist
        </div>

        <div tal:replace="structure provider:plone.belowcontentbody" />

    </tal:main-macro>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

I've also done a search for at_download and found /Plone/portal_skins/archetypes/at_download.  It contains this code:

```
if traverse_subpath:
    field = context.getWrappedField(traverse_subpath[0])
else:
    field = context.getPrimaryField()
return field.download(context)
```

Can anyone tell what I need to change to make PDFs view in the browser?

Currently when I select a link to a PDF it looks like this.  http://intranet.internal.lan/somewhere/Test.pdf/at_download/file

I need it to look like this.

http://intranet.internal.lan/somewhere/Test.pdf

(without /at_download/file)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

David

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's work in plone 3.x.x, but
I am using plone 4.1.6 and I wanted to render a pdf file
in a browser (worked in chrome and firefox) and put like this
in a page tamplate:

```
<a tal:attributes="href string:${edicao_url}/@@images/field_pdf"  target="_blank">View PDF</a>
```

where the url shows:

http://localhost:8080/plone_site/content-type/@@images/field_pdf/

So, the field field_pdf is an attribute from a content-type!
Ah, and I am using too a content type from Dexterity!

I hope this help help you! =D

Answer (score 0):

You right, you need something like this:

```xml
<object id="pdfRenderer" data="/path/to/document.pdf" type="application/pdf" style="height: 700px;">
    </object>
```

This can be achieved by trigger a download of the file if you don't append `view` to the url.

For example:

- http://intranet.internal.lan/somewhere/Test.pdf/view: Shows the default file view (This is Plone default)
- http://intranet.internal.lan/somewhere/Test.pdf: Should trigger a download

For triggering the download you have to implement this on your file type or patch the existing one.
A possible entry point ist the `FileFied` `index_html` method.

This is a working example for Plone 4.3.x:

```python
from plone.app.blob import field
from plone.app.blob.download import handleIfModifiedSince, handleRequestRange
from urllib import quote
from webdav.common import rfc1123_date
from zope.component import getMultiAdapter


class FileField(field.FileField):

    def index_html(self, instance, REQUEST=None, RESPONSE=None,
                   charset='utf-8', disposition='inline'):
        """Kicks download.
        Writes data including file name and content type to RESPONSE
        """

        if REQUEST is None:
            REQUEST = instance.REQUEST

        if RESPONSE is None:
            RESPONSE = REQUEST.RESPONSE

        RESPONSE.setHeader('Last-Modified', rfc1123_date(instance._p_mtime))
        RESPONSE.setHeader('Content-Type', self.getContentType(instance))
        RESPONSE.setHeader('Accept-Ranges', 'bytes')

        if handleIfModifiedSince(instance, REQUEST, RESPONSE):
            return ''

        length = self.get_size(instance)
        RESPONSE.setHeader('Content-Length', length)

        filename = self.getFilename(instance)
        if filename is not None:
            if isinstance(filename, unicode):
                filename = filename.encode(charset, errors="ignore")

            # Create a user agent specific disposition header
            # IE needs an url quoted filename
            # Other browsers need an unquoted filename
            user_agent = REQUEST.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT', '')
            if 'MSIE' in user_agent:
                header_value = '%s; filename=%s' % (disposition,
                                                    quote(filename))
            else:
                header_value = '%s; filename="%s"' % (disposition, filename)
            RESPONSE.setHeader("Content-disposition", header_value)

        request_range = handleRequestRange(instance, length, REQUEST, RESPONSE)

        # Notify file downloads, but do not notify range requests
        if not ('start' in request_range and request_range['start'] > 0):
            portal_state = getMultiAdapter((instance, instance.REQUEST),
                                           name='plone_portal_state')

        return self.get(instance).getIterator(**request_range)
```

You should really consider to upgrade your Plone site before implement new features, which may block you again!!

Comment: Hi Mathias.  I don't mean to be completely clueless, but I can't even find what you are talking about in my version of Plone.  I wanted to do what this guy [link](http://www.kcsts.co.uk/blog/embedded-pdf-in-file-view-with-plone) did, but I need help adapting it to my older version of Plone.  I fully intend to upgrade to the current version of Plone, but that will have to wait till the new year.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to adapt the Plone 4.2.x implementation to your 3.0.6 environment. The code I posted is for the `FileField`, in your case this would be somewhere in `Products.Archetypes`, or `Products.ATContentTypes`. You need to patch the FielField in order to use the file path directly (download starts without redirect to at_download).You need to find the `FileField` and patch the index_html method, which directly delivers the file content. The above code ist a implementation with stream iterators, which allows start/pause a download. Please extend your Q, so I can adapt my A.